# Why isn't http server consuming a lot of CPU?

Tags: performance, http, networking, polling

The server should response as soon as possible, isn't the server process always polling if there are requests?
So, it would like a while loop. But why is not CPU(single core) all consumed if there is no visit?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details like what server software and how it's configured.  In general server's do not actively poll, they have the OS notify them when a new connection/data is available.  Until then they just sleep.

Comment: @kicken Really sorry that I do not know much about server details; I meant the general intuition. Do you mean that it's some mechanism like hardware interruption?

Answer (score 3):

> isn't the server process always polling?

Not if that's a reasonable implementation.

There are many implementations of HTTP servers, and communication servers in general, and polling is not a suitable architecture for any of these.

For example, some servers rely on asynchronous I/O operations using events, callbacks and so on. Other implementations rely on blocking socket APIs while operating in multi threaded modes, and there could be other architectures as well...

Comment: For using blocking socket APIs, when blocked, the process is stopped and is not consuming CPU; Is it?

Comment: @heLomaN - That's right.

Comment: For using `asynchronous I/O`, requests will trigger some actions to handle them. There is not a while main loop,  but why the process is not terminated?  A software with procedural programming should exit after running even it register some callbacks; then how be called when not running?

Comment: @heLomaN - the answer is OS & implementation dependent. I suggest you read about async I/O for your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> isn't the server process always polling if there are requests?

No. It is *blocking*, in either an `accept()` call or a `select()` call. No polling.

Comment: FTR, there are other options (probably more likely) such as `epoll_wait()` -- and that's if we're not talking about Windows.